# Save image is SharedPreferences after Image is get from camera or upload from gallery and display at ImageView (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I have a problem as mention at the question above. All data from EditText, RadioButton and Spinner can be saved at SharedPreference and display back at another activity. But i dont know how to save the Image after I get it from camera or upload from gallery and display at ImageView. Any method? Please help me.

//Code for saving in SharedPreferences

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("title",etTitle.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("year",etYear.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("month",etMonth.getText().toString());

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = rgSuggestWill.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
            editor.putString("suggestionwill",radioButton.getText().toString());
            if (spReviewer.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Please choose")){

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewSuggestion.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please choose your reviewer");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }else{
                editor.putString("reviewer",spReviewer.getSelectedItem().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion.this,NewSuggestion2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

//code for recall from SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title",DEFAULT);
    String year = sharedPreferences.getString("year",DEFAULT);
    String month =  sharedPreferences.getString("month",DEFAULT);
    String present =  sharedPreferences.getString("present",DEFAULT);
    String details = sharedPreferences.getString("details",DEFAULT);
    String benefit =  sharedPreferences.getString("benefit",DEFAULT);
    String suggestionwill =  sharedPreferences.getString("suggestionwill",DEFAULT);
    String reviewer =  sharedPreferences.getString("reviewer",DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not store the image in SharedPreferences, you should save an image to sd-card and then save the image path from sd-card into SharedPreferences ->

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("YourImagePathTag","YourImagePath").commit;
```

then you can get the image from this path. Also, you can save the path into the database which is safer than this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the image using preference, instead use the SQLite for saving and retrieving by use "blob"

//Convert your bitmap to base64

```
public static String encodeBitmapTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
    byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImageString = 
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
    return encodedImageString ;
}
```

//Save the image in preferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor= myPrefrence.edit();
prefEditor.putString("key", encodeBitmapTobase64(yourbitmap));
prefEditor.commit();
```

// get encoded string from pref and convert base64 string to bitmap

```
public static Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String encodedString) {
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString , 0, 
    decodedString.length);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description about the answer.Please refer  [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]

Answer (score 0):

saving the image in the sharedpreference(by string) is not a good method.
make the image to the bytearray or uri(after save in the EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and use the intent.putextra

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting the selected image for example from gallery in onActivityResult() method then you can save the path string from Uri like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result code is RESULT_OK only if the user selects an Image
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE:
                //data.getData returns the content URI for the selected Image
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("KEY_IMAGE", selectedImage.getPath()).apply();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if from camera?

Comment: same process just add the camera request code and do the same with camera image data.